# Regresión por quantiles por categoria en R usando quantreg

Tags: r, regresión-lineal

Teniendo la siguiente base de datos.

```
df <- data.frame(C1=c('A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C'),
             C2=c('1','2','3','1','3','5','6','0','2'),
             C3=c(10,20,40,60,70,10,20,60,90),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Quisiera calcular una regresión lineal para el quantil 95 entre C2 y C3 usando `quantreg` separadamente para cada factor de la columna C1 (A, B C). El código que tengo hasta ahora es:

```
library(quantreg) 
fit1 <- rq(C3 ~ C2, tau = .05, data = df) 
summary(df)
```

Comment: Por favor, comparte el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora. Saludos,

Comment: library(quantreg) 
fit1 <- rq(C3 ~ C2, tau = .05, data = df)
summary(df)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no te entendí mal, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
# aplicamos rq a cada set de datos dado C1
lapply(unique(df$C1), 
       FUN = function(x) {tmp <- df[df$C1==x,];rq(C3 ~ C2, tau = .05, data = tmp)}
) -> model_lst
# Renombramos los elementos de la lista al nombre de C1
model_lst <- setNames(model_lst, unique(df$C1))

# ahora sí podemos acceder a cada modelo 
model_lst[["A"]]
model_lst[["B"]]
model_lst[["C"]]
```

Básicamente, por cada set de datos correspondiente al valor de `C1`, aplicamos la regresión `rq()`, al finalizar, tendremos una lista con cada uno de los modelos.

Comment: Una consulta relacionada a esto. Las regresiones por cuantiles están calculadas lineales. Puede calcularse según otro modelo, por ejemplo: bilinear, cuadrática, por ejemplo?

Comment: Pareciera que sí: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249595/quantile-regression-for-non-linear-regression-analysis

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio!